# HashSet<T> performance (compared to ObservableCollection<T>)?

Tags: c#, performance, observablecollection, hashset

I am currently working on a project where I have to manage large sets of unique elements. Each element has ~20 Properties, and every element has a public property DateTime.

The property DateTime is not unique, so I cannot use a generic dictionary to store my data.

Currently I put those elements into an ObservableCollection, but the perfomance of removing elements from the collection is incredibly slow, I end up waiting ~20 seconds to remove ~7000 elements from a collection of ~25.000 elements.

(The search operation seems to be quite efficient, it takes only ~30 ms to find 80 randomly selected elements from an unsorted collection of 300.000 elements).

Each element implements the GetHashCode() method by simply returning the DateTime.GetHashCode().

I thought that using a HashSet rather than an ObservableCollection would increase my performance quite a bit, but it doesn't seem to have an effect at all...

And using a generic dictionary is even worse...

Isn't the HashSet more powerful than an ObservableCollection if the elements have "good" hash functions (there are very few elements that have the same hash code)??

Comment: `HashSet<T>` must also be unique.

Comment: But if DateTime property is *not* unique (according to the post) why do you use GetHashCode() of that non  unique property ?

Comment: An ObservableCollection and HashSet don't serve the same purpose. What are the reasons why you started using an ObservableCollection? Are you binding it to a WPF or Silverlight control? The HashSet offers constant time performance for basic operations (add, remove, contains and size).

Comment: @Tigran, because hashset is not a dictionary? all items in hashset are unique, hash code is not, so .net place and search an item using hashcode as starting value. GetHashCode() is not guaranteeing uniqueness, it serves as hash key to evenly distribute items in hash set.

Comment: The DateTime property is NOT unique, but there are very few collisions.

Comment: I do not want to bind to the collection, but I want to execute code, when it changes.

Comment: It would help to see your code here, how do you know the performance issue is with HashSet itself and not with your notifications?  Third rule of optimization is "profile first"...

Comment: Are you 'observing' the ObservableCollection? Could your 'obvserver' code be the reason for the performance problems? I would be called when you deleted.

Comment: if removing the items is slow could you flag the items as deleted instead and only ever add to the observable collection?  You might be able to use Tuple<Element,bool> in the collection rather than Element and as long as the Tuple uses the hash of both elements, and you always search by Tuple<Element,false> then you should never match a deleted one, as its hash will have changed, even though it'll be in the same bucket.  Of course this means your collection will always grow and eventually performance will degrade...

Comment: @n8wrl: Thanks, the process of removing elements from the ObservableCollection is now faster, but still very slow...

Comment: @EhssanDoust: does that `ObservableCollection` is binded to something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override the [Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx) method of your objects.

Because the [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) uses an internal [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) instance that usually first checks for (null) and then compares a "non-null" item with another item by using the overridden *Equals* method:

```
class MyObject
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (other is MyObject)
        {
            // use the 'Id' property as identifier

            MyObject myObj = (MyObject)obj;
            return myObj.Id == this.Id;
        }

        // is not a 'MyObject' based object
        return base.Equals(other);
    }
}
```

You can also use strings or any other kind of objects that are comparable with your objects.

EDIT:

So you can use the HashSet instead of [OberservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx). The last collection type is normally slower because on each collection change (add, remove, clear, insert, etc.) the [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged) and the [CollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.collectionchanged) events are fired.

Answer (score 2):

You can optimize the performance of the `ObservableCollection` by reducing the change notifications. I've written a custom collection class, the `ItemCollection`, with an update mechanism (`BeginUpdate`/`EndUpdate`):

```
  ItemCollection<Customer> customers = new ItemCollection<Customer>
  customers.BeginUpdate();
  customers.Add( new Customer( "Joe", "Smith" ) );
  customers.Add( new Customer( "Mary", "Jones" ) );
  customers.Add( new Customer( "Lisa", "Black" ) );
  customers.Add( new Customer( "Peter", "Brown" ) );
  customers.EndUpdate();
```

Article with source code: [Presentation Patterns for XAML based Applications](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380265/Presentation-Patterns-for-XAML-based-Applications).

Answer (score 2):

Well Marcel answer is correct, but if performance really matters you can slightly improve his equals method:

```
class MyObject
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        MyObject myObj = obj as MyObject;

        if (myObj != null)
        {
            // use the 'Id' property as identifier
            return myObj.Id == this.Id;
        }

        // is not a 'MyObject' based object
        return base.Equals(other);
    }
}
```

With this approach you avoid the *costly* function to check if a object is of a specifc type two times by calling it only once and doing a fast null check. For more informations about it, you could take a look into [this article from Eric](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/16/is-is-as-or-is-as-is.aspx).